# How to schedule a functions to run everyday with NodeJS and Generators?

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, generator, schedule, node-cron

I need a function to be called every day at a given hour **with generators** (yields), doing my search I've found out two node modules that enable me to do this, one is [node-schedule](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)
and the other one is [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)

*Node-cron* **does not seems** to support generators

*Node-schedule* should have the support but it seems to **not work** as pointed out here: [issue #325](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/issues/325)

To be more clear about what I'm trying to accomplish I attach the same code the issue #325 has:

```
const date = momemt().add(1, 's'); // 1 second after now.
schedule.scheduleJob('taksid', date, function*(){
    console.log('Hi');
    const result = yield Message.findAll();
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
});
```

As specified in the issue, 'Hi' gets printed out while 'result' does not.

I'm not able to find out a way to schedule a function with generators, if some of you know how to do it that would be great! Thank in advance guys

Comment: Well, how do you expect the function to be resumed? Generator functions are not like async functions, if they are not explicitly iterated through, they will pause at the first yield. You need to write a driver that will step through the function appropriately, especially if `Message.findAll()` is an asynchronous function, which I'm assuming it is.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem "How to schedule a functions to run everyday with NodeJS and Generators?" on friday and just now after the weekend I came up with a solution. Maybe it might solve your problem as well.

The first step is to create a shell file. I'm using Windows 10 so you might have to adapt it if using Mac.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " # Starting Scraper ..."
  pkill -f "node fileWithYieldToBeScheduled.js"
  sleep 1
  node fileWithYieldToBeScheduled.js -D
  status=$?
  if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Failed to start node: $status"
      exit $status
    else
      echo "Success"      
  fi
```

Explanation: Name this "myFancyFileToScheduleYields.sh" and place it in your root directory. Next create a "scheduleYields.js" with the following content.

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');
var cron = require('node-cron');

/**
 * Your task to be scheduled.
 */
const startFileWithYields= function () {
  childProcess.exec(__dirname + "/myFancyFileToScheduleYields.sh", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(stderr);
    }

    console.log(stdout);
  });
}

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * *', function () {
  startFileWithYields();
});
```

Finally do "node scheduleYields.js" and observe how the magic happens.

This will run the task every 5 Minute according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron#using-step-values). Now go and adapt it to your usecase and give feedback if it worked.

I even tested this with Docker and and works as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works better as the first one mentioned above by using [**vo**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vo). Applying my usecase to yours you would have to do the following. Extract the generator from your function and put it into a "search.js"

```
function* findAll() {
    console.log('Hi');
    const result = yield Message.findAll();
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
}

exports.findAll = function() {
  vo(findAll)(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("It worked!");
  });
}
```

Create another file where you schedule your task as shown below.

```
const search = require('./search');

const WAIT_SEK = 30;
const WAIT_MS = WAIT_SEK * 1000;

let countSek = 0;

const loopSearch = setInterval(() => {

  if ((countSek % WAIT_SEK) === 0) {
    search.findAll();
    countSek = 0;
  }

  console.log(`Next search in: ${(WAIT_SEK - countSek)}`)

  countSek += 1;

}, 1000);
```

**Explanation**: This will run your task each 30 seconds and give you feedback each second.

The solution works in Docker as well!